# Express return post info to be processed by another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, header

I have this code:

```
 app.post('/pst', function(req, res) {
            var data = req.body.convo;

            res.render('waiting.ejs');  //ADDED THIS

            myFunc(data).then(result => {


            res.render('success.ejs');  //THEN THIS

            //---------------------------------
            //clever way to send text file to client from the memory of the server
            var fileContents = Buffer.from(result, 'ascii');
            var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
            readStream.end(fileContents);
            res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            readStream.pipe(res);
            //--------------------------------------

            }).catch( .....
```

What i want to do is when there is a POST,
1. grab the post information
2. do a res.render()
3. run a function with the post information as its parameters
4. do this code snippet that will allow the client to download stuff from the memory as a .txt file
5. do another res.render()

Everything works if we exclude the two res.render(). After i do one, i cannot set the headers. I get this error.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

So i thought of a potential solution.

Is it possible that the app.post() will get the post data and do a res.render().

Then, return the post data, so another part of the code will handle calling the function with this data as parameter and then do the header manipulation thing, then finally do the last res.render().

Keep in mind this is the routes.js file.

Comment: The res functions should always be the last you call. You can't have multiple `res.render()`s.

Comment: Thats why i am asking if i only do one res.render here, but i send the post data to be processed elsewhere, where i can do another.

Comment: In what part of that code are you sending off data to be processed?

Comment: myFunc(data).then(result   . data is the data from the POST and myFunc is an asynchronous function.

Comment: Yeah, but you are still rendering to the same `res`

Comment: So how can i render another one elsewhere?

Comment: What do you mean with *elsewhere*?

Comment: I want to do a res.render() that say "wait your data is being processed." Then when the function finished, feed the data to the client (by setting headers) then do another res.render() that says "you are done"

Comment: You have to do that with JS and get requests on the client, it won't be possible with multiple res.... Functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is a request/response protocol.  A client makes a request and gets one and only one response back.  So, you can never call `res.render()` twice on the same request.

Your problem is really defined by this desired sequence:

1. Client sends request
2. Server starts to process request
3. Client shows progress
4. Server finishes processing request
5. Client shows final result

There are a number of ways to accomplish that:

**Client uses Ajax instead of form post to send request**

1. Client submits form via Ajax instead of form post
2. Client puts up progress on the page using DOM manipulation (changing of the current page contents, usually showing a visual overlay of some type)
3. Server works on request, not returning anything yet
4. Server finishes request and returns response to client with one `res.render()`
5. Client either inserts the returned content into the current page or issues a `window.location = xxxx` to change the current page to show new URL containing new contents.

**Form post response that uses webSocket/socket.io to get final results**

1. Client submits form
2. Server returns immediately response page that shows progress/waiting UI and that page also connects a webSocket or socket.io connection to the server
3. Server works on request
4. Server accepts webSocket or socket.io connection
5. Server finishes request and sends some type of result over webSocket/socket.io connection to the correct client
6. Client receives response over webSocket/socket.io and either updates the contents of the current page or changes page to a new URL

**All done via webSocket/socket.io**

1. Client loads original page
2. Client establishes webSocket/socket.io connection to server
3. Client sends form data to server over webSocket/socket.io connection
4. Client puts up progress/waiting overlay
5. Server starts processing request
6. Server finishes processing request
7. Server sends response from request back to client over webSocket/socket.io connection for that client.
8. Client receives response over webSocket/socket.io connection and either updates the contents of the current page or changes page to a new URL

Comment: Just when i thought i was done with my application... Now i have to learn socket.io lol. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user1584421 - The first option does not need socket.io.  If you have no other reason to use socket.io, I would think the first option would work just fine unless your server takes so long to process the request that the browser times out the request.

Comment: I dont know Ajax. And i am tense on time. Are you aware of a tutorial that will cover jus that, or maybe even an question here on SO, or maybe working piece of code for the first option?

Comment: @user1584421 - Are you using any client-side framework like jQuery that would have simple Ajax support built-in?  For modern browsers, the [`fetch()` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) built into those browsers is pretty easy to use.

Comment: No its all node and express. The client side is minimal.Should i read about fetch()?

Comment: @user1584421 - I'm not asking about server-side.  I'm asking about what's in your web pages.  Is it all just plain HTML with no Javascript?  Yes, I gave you a  link to read about `fetch()`.  It's very simple to use.  But, if you're going to modify the current web page, you will have to learn some basic DOM manipulation (which will be generally useful anyway).

Comment: Yes it is plain HTML. No js at all! I do not know client side stuff. But i can learn quickly, as long as i dont waste time learning stuff i dont need. Since i am short on time. So i guess fetch will handle the POST and then do DOM manipulation in order to change the web page the user is currently at?

Comment: Could you provide some example of a fetch form working with node? How will the form post body will be passed to node so i can insert it into my async function?

Comment: @user1584421 - A properly done Ajax call can look to the server exactly the same as a regular form post.

Comment: Cant i use a normal form post to Node and just do the DOM manipulation with fetch()?

Comment: @user1584421 - No.  `fetch()` doesn't do DOM manipulation.  It makes an HTTP request to your server.

Comment: But i can do this already. I just need to change the webpage after the user clicks the form button.