# Node DOM manipulation on the page after a POST

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can i change the webpage the user is currently at after he forms a POST request?

I am using Node serverside (maybe that is relevant).

The problem is that i can only do one response per request. And i have to do more than one response for a request.

Comment: It depends on whether it is a client-side or server-side rendered application. If it is server-side rendered you can make the redirect from your server once the POST request succeeds. If it is client-side then you do this on the client instead

Comment: The rest of the context for this question is here: [Express return post info to be processed by another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065832/express-return-post-info-to-be-processed-by-another-function) as this appears to be a follow-on based on the possible solutions to that prior question.

Comment: i researched another approach. loading the two pages in my webpage, then display one of them at a time using something like document.getElementById(“myDiv”).style.display = “none”;   Now i am searching of how the css activation/deactivation will be triggered when the user clicks the form's submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this.
You put both pages inside the one page.
The two contents go to separate divs.

Then you use something like this code:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('.div2').style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function(e){
            document.querySelector('.div1').style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector('.div2').style.display = "block";
    });
</script>
```