# Node Impossible to res.render() or res.redirect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, header, request, httpresponse

This is my code:

```
app.post('/post_route', function(req, res) {

        //HACKY CODE TO SERVE THE CLIENT A TEXT FILE
        var fileContents = Buffer.from(result, 'ascii');
        var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
        readStream.end(fileContents);
        res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        readStream.pipe(res);

        res.redirect('/success');
});
```

The first part sends some portion of the memory of the server to the client as a text file.
Once this is finished, i want to redirect the user to a success page.

This does not work.

I also have this code in my routes.js file:

```
app.get('/success', function(req, res) {
        res.render('success.ejs');
});
```

No matter whether i try to do a `res.render('succes.ejs');` directly, or using a `res.redirect()` it will not work.

This probably has to do with the 'One request -> one response' principle.
But here i am not doing a direct response before i try to do the render/redirect.

I have only set up some headers to allow the downloading.

So is there a way to circumvent or hack this in order to manage to do the render/redirect?

Comment: Hello again. `res.redirect()` is setting the `Location` header in the background, meaning it's also setting headers after they are sent.

Comment: So its impossible?

Comment: I managed to display the first page by putting all the pages in one then controlling which parts will be shown with javascript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066509/node-dom-manipulation-on-the-page-after-a-post

Comment: What is impossible is doing both piping to the client *and* redirecting them.

Comment: At least, after the piping is done... Is there a way to notify the client side, so i can render a different div?